# Is there any way to make a class name a parameter and use this as a class

Tags: c#

I need a requirement that I need to change the 'homepage' class dynamically to another class having these same fields

```
Resources.homepage.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(CI, true, true);
```

Is there any way to get the class name in a variable and execute this dynamically. I dont need to repeat the code for every classes.

Comment: Are you looking for [`GetType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfwy45w9(v=vs.110).aspx) method?

Comment: @JenishRabadiya I think it's more likely he needs to learn about interfaces (or less likely generics)

Comment: You can use [Reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection(v=vs.110).aspx) or [Templates/Generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx) for this.

Comment: @UmairM Wrong in C#. Why you mention "templates" when generics != templates...

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer in c++ they are templates and c++ people refer `<T>`  things as templates. thanks for correction anyway :)

Comment: @UmairM And is this question about C++ or C#? And you should read about the fact that templates != generics even when the syntax is similar.........

Comment: I know the fact, i just mentioned it incase if he doesn't know about Generics as he seems newbie so he might get a clue that what i am talking about.